# Unable to lauch paytm UPI on webview disabled devices

Tags: android, android-webview, deep-linking, paytm

I am trying to deeplink to paytm UPI on Android. It is working fine on normal devices but devices with diabled android system Webview it is not going to UPI and showing "No apps can perform this action".

---

Note:- Latest version of Google Chrome is installed and is also set to default app.
If there is any improvement for this code please let me know.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay").buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("pa", "paytm-********@paytm")
                .appendQueryParameter("pn", "Demo")
                .appendQueryParameter("tr", txnID)
                .appendQueryParameter("mc", "****")
                .appendQueryParameter("tn", "Payment against Order: " + txnID)
                .appendQueryParameter("am", 
ServiceUtility.chkNull(MyApplication.cartTotal).toString().trim())  
//ServiceUtility.chkNull(MyApplication.cartTotal).toString().trim()
                .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
                .build();

        Logger.error("proceedToMakeUPI", "uri " + uri);

        Intent upiPayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        upiPayIntent.setData(uri);

        ComponentName name = new ComponentName("net.one97.paytm", 
"net.one97.paytm.upi.deeplink.UPIDeeplinkActivity");
        upiPayIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        upiPayIntent.setComponent(name);

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");

        if (null != chooser.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager())) {
            Logger.error("proceedToMakeUPI", "UPI Payment resolved to activity");
            startActivityForResult(chooser, REQ_UPIPAYMENT);
        } else {
            Logger.error("proceedToMakeUPI", "No activity found to handle UPI Payment");
        }
```

Comment: You can use android sdk of paytm - https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/android-sdk/

Comment: Paytm SDK is already implemented and is working well. My issue is with paytm UPI deeplink not working on non webview devices.